# Checking if selected user is a bot. (discordpy)

Tags: python, discord.py

I am making a giveaway command, and would like to check if a randomly selected user is a bot or not.

How exactly can I do that?

```
   user = discord.Member
    
   if not user.bot:
      winner = random.choice(ctx.guild.members)
    
      await channel.send(f"Congratulations! {winner.mention} won {prize}!")
```

Error:

```
> Traceback:

Command raised an exception: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'winner' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: There's no way the code shown could generate that error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't call a variable that has not been initialized, `user = discord.Member` does nothing. You can do it something like this (I did *not* test this):

```py
winner = random.choice(ctx.guild.members)

# Just do it over if it is a bot
while (winner.bot):
  winner = random.choice(ctx.guild.members)

await channel.send(f"Congratulations! {winner.mention} won {prize}!")
```

As Lukasz Wiecek suggested in the comments it is also possible to do this below. Just note that the `:=` (walrus-) operator which is used to assign variables while an expression is evaluated is added in **Python 3.8**

```py
# Just do it over if it is a bot
while (winner := random.choice(ctx.guild.members).bot):
  pass

await channel.send(f"Congratulations! {winner.mention} won {prize}!")
```

Comment: It works now without errors, but it still can select a random bot..

Comment: Yeah, i did a little oopsie, the condition in the `while` should not contain `not`, that makes sure it selects a bot.. I fixed it

Comment: Could be written without calling `random.choice` twice using `white (winner := random.choice(ctx.guild.members)).bot: pass` (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/)

Answer (score 1):

You can filter `ctx.guild.members` first:

```
eligible = [member for member in ctx.guild.members if not member.bot]
winner = random.choice(eligible)
await channel.send(f"Congratulations! {winner.mention} won {prize}!")
```

This completely removes the need for a while loop.
Also please note that if all members are bots `random.choice` will raise an exception.
With `while` the behavior is endless loop.